# Scalability Location Distance Search Over 100,000 LatLng Positions Across USA

Tags: c#, sql, distance, geo, haversine

**Scenario =**

1) Delivery Offices spread out across the USA each specifying their own maximum delivery radius limit in miles.

2) A target address geo converted to LatLng is the delivery destination.

**Goal** = To return a dataset of Delivery Offices (1) who's delivery radius limit falls within this distance to the target address(2)

**Attempt =**

As a starting point to my problem I am using the excellent work example by the Storm consultancy in identifying the closest office to a customer: [Haversine distance between two points](https://www.stormconsultancy.co.uk/blog/development/code-snippets/the-haversine-formula-in-c-and-sql/)

My 'Offices' table stores the office address along with their Lat and Lng values AND also their maximum distance 'deliveryLimit'.

The SQL to calculate the Haversine blows my mind and is currently beyond my understanding!
The Storm SQL is below, but instead of selecting only one row from straight distance calculations, I need to select all offices rows who's max distance delivery limit is less than the distance between the office and the customer.

**Question1** = How do I add the max distance limit filter into the SQL query so that it returns the offices with a delivery zone which includes the target location?

**Question2** = How can I limit the number of offices queried to those that realistically could be in the target area of the USA?
For instance, if the target location is Boise, Idaho and offices in LA, California have a delivery distance limit of 300 miles. There is no point in even querying such offices. However, offices in Washington; Oregon and Northern Nevada states who border Idaho should be included in the search query as some could possibly have maximum distance values which reach this example of Boise, ID.

The SQL for Haversine as used by Storm:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *, ( 3960 * acos( cos( radians( @custLat ) ) *
cos( radians( Lat ) ) * cos( radians(  Lng  ) - radians( @custLng ) ) +
sin( radians( @custLat ) ) * sin( radians(  Lat  ) ) ) ) AS Distance
FROM Offices
ORDER BY Distance ASC
```

The SQL example above selects only the closest office to the target lat/long (@custLng)

Storm approached the distance calculation from two different directions. The SQL above was the first. The second was by keeping the office coordinates in an in-memory List and creating a method with function to loop over the List calculating the distances and finally selecting the closest like so:

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns the distance in miles or kilometers of any two
/// latitude / longitude points.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="pos1">Location 1</param>
/// <param name="pos2">Location 2</param>
/// <param name="unit">Miles or Kilometers</param>
/// <returns>Distance in the requested unit</returns>
public double HaversineDistance(LatLng pos1, LatLng pos2, DistanceUnit unit)
{
    double R = (unit == DistanceUnit.Miles) ? 3960 : 6371;
    var lat = (pos2.Latitude - pos1.Latitude).ToRadians();
    var lng = (pos2.Longitude - pos1.Longitude).ToRadians();
    var h1 = Math.Sin(lat / 2) * Math.Sin(lat / 2) +
              Math.Cos(pos1.Latitude.ToRadians()) * 
              Math.Cos(pos2.Latitude.ToRadians()) *
              Math.Sin(lng / 2) * Math.Sin(lng / 2);
    var h2 = 2 * Math.Asin(Math.Min(1, Math.Sqrt(h1)));
    return R * h2;
}

public enum DistanceUnit { Miles, Kilometers };
```

and

```
var Offices = GetMyOfficeList();
for(int i = 0; i< Offices.Count; i++)
{
    Offices[i].Distance = HaversineDistance(
                        coord,
                        new LatLng(Offices[i].Lat, Offices[i].Lng),
                        DistanceUnit.Miles);
}

var closestOffice = Offices.OrderBy(x => x.Distance).Take(1).Single();
```

Scalability is important as my scenario could easily end up with a lot more than 100,000 office locations, so an in-memory office list option is unlikely!

Comment: Are you using Sql2008 or newer, and if so is it possible to store your office location in a geometry data type? If you are many options open up to you to make this problem much much easier.

Comment: You can also reduce the number of offices you need to do the expensive query on quite simply by e.g. selecting a 600-mile-or-slightly-larger square using bounds on the lat and long numbers of the office as a subquery, then feed the results of that into the more complex calculation. If you wanted to do that by partition, then e.g. divide the country up into 600-mile squares: assign each office to a square, create a table indicating which squares are adjacent, look up your delivery location's square then compute the set of offices in that square and all adjacent squares to query.

Comment: Scott - yes to using Sql2008 or newer. Sure its possible to store each office location into a geometry data type - certainly interested to learn more about what options are available to make it easier ?

Comment: Rup - Thats a sure way of reducing the number of queries - thank you for sharing the insight.

Comment: What version of sql are you on? They added some new stuff to 2012 that would help me write up an answer.

Comment: Scott - its a VPS via Arvixe hosting - currently SQL Server 2008R2 and IIS7 and don't see any migration to 2012 on the horizon.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Sql2008 or newer it has specific types built in to make what you want to do easier. The main type you will need to use is [`geography`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280766%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

I am going to make some guesses at your table structure, but the main thing is you have a `Location` and a `DeleveryArea`

```sql
create table Offices
(
  OfficeName varchar(40),
  Location geography,
  DeliveryDistance float, --stored in miles
  --If you are on SQL2008 or 2008R2 replace BufferWithCurves with one of the older Buffer functions
  DeliveryArea as Location.BufferWithCurves(DeliveryDistance * 1609.34) PERSISTED, --1609.34 converts miles to meters 
)
```

I used [BufferWithCurves](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929273.aspx) in my above example, but that is only available on Sql2012 and newer, if you are on 2008 or 2008R2 you will need to use either [BufferWithTolerance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933987.aspx) or [STBuffer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933965.aspx) or just manually define your own area by hand in the insert statment.

Now to populate the data, because we made `DeliveryArea` a calculated persisted column it is actually pretty easy to do. All you need to do is put in the location of the office and the radius of its delivery area and it will calculate the circle for the area for you. I will use the examples you provided in your question:

```sql
insert into Offices (OfficeName, Location, DeliveryDistance) 
values ('Boise, ID', 
        geography::Point(43.6187102,-116.2146068, 4326), --4326 represents a "lat and long" coordinate system
        300
       )

insert into Offices (OfficeName, Location,DeliveryDistance) 
values ('LA, CA', 
        geography::Point(34.0204989,-118.4117325, 4326),
        300
       )

insert into Offices (OfficeName, Location,DeliveryDistance) 
values ('Walla Walla, WI', 
        geography::Point(46.0627549,-118.3337259, 4326),
        300
       )

insert into Offices (OfficeName, Location,DeliveryDistance) 
values ('Baker City, OR', 
        geography::Point(44.7746169,-117.8317284, 4326),
        300
       )

insert into Offices (OfficeName, Location,DeliveryDistance) 
values ('Elko, NV', 
        geography::Point(40.846931,-115.7669825, 4326),
        300
       )
```

Now for your query, if you wanted to find which delivery areas serviced [Jordan Vally, Oregon](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Jordan+Valley,+OR+97910/@42.9436938,-116.2187835,6z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x54b19ace44329241:0x2d8260a1b93c9e88) (42.9740245,-117.0533247) your query would simply be

```sql
declare @cust geography = geography::Point(42.9740245,-117.0533247, 4326)

SELECT OfficeName, 
       Location.STDistance(@cust) / 1609.34 AS Distance, --convert back to miles
       Location.Lat as Lat,
       Location.Long as Lng
FROM Offices
where  DeliveryArea.STContains(@cust) = 1
ORDER BY Distance asc
```

And this would give you all Offices that the location you chose is within the delivery area. The real nice thing about this system is if instead of calculating `DeleveryArea` based of the location and delevery range you could actually give it a set of points to outline a non circular geographic area, like a city.

With a well planned [Spatial Index](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964712%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) this solution should work for even your 100,000 location record set. If you want to learn more about some of the benefits of using `geography` see [this SO question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7307147/how-good-is-the-geography-datatype-in-sql-server-2008).

[Here is a SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d1c31/1) with all of the queries I put above shown in a working example.

Comment: Scott - WOW ! That is the kind of answer and detail which not only helps me visualize what you are talking about, but bound to help many more who come across this post.  Thank You Scott for the time and detail you put into this, I truly appreciate it.  I am going to run tests and try out each solution path of the valued replies on this page before I check my prefered answer - so it will be some time before I close this one.  Thanks again to all who have submitted help  :)

Comment: @MartinSansone-MiOEE just be sure to read up on how to do Spatial indexes before you run your tests and be sure to add them to your test tables. Like any other normal indexes if you set them up incorrectly they will not be used in your queries providing no help at all and just add overhead to the database.

Answer (score 1):

You already have the distance between the office and the target location. Return only those offices whose distance is less than or equal to their delivery radius:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT Id, DeliveryRadius, ( 3960 * acos( cos( radians( @custLat ) ) *
    cos( radians( Lat ) ) * cos( radians(  Lng  ) - radians( @custLng ) ) +
    sin( radians( @custLat ) ) * sin( radians(  Lat  ) ) ) ) AS Distance
    FROM Offices)
WHERE Distance <= DeliveryRadius
ORDER BY Distance ASC
```

Your second question asks how offices can be partitioned so that a search considers a subset of offices; I would first ensure that your search is not performant enough given your dataset and latency requirements before considering doing this.

Comment: Jason, thank you for the improvement and showing me where the extra Select needed to go.  I foresee that the query request would be called many times within a short amount of time, hence my concern over the performance as the dataset grows, hence my interest in setting up the architecture from the start to avoid the probable bottleneck.  I shall create a set of sample data and run tests as you suggest :)

Answer (score 1):

For a @Raduis in miles:

```
DECLARE @RadiusInDegrees decimal(18,15)
SET @RadiusInDegrees = @Radius / 69.11 * 1.4142
```

@Radius / 69.11 gives radius in degrees, but it needs to be multiplied by root 2 to cover the entire square bounding area.

```
SELECT
    @LatitudeLow = @Latitude - @RadiusInDegrees,
    @LatitudeHigh = @Latitude + @RadiusInDegrees,       
    @LongitudeLow = @Longitude - @RadiusInDegrees,
    @LongitudeHigh = @Longitude + @RadiusInDegrees
```

Using a bounding area limits the number of times expensive exact distance calculations are made.

```
[...]
WHERE
    [Latitude] > @LatitudeLow  
    AND [Latitude] < @LatitudeHigh 
    AND [Longitude] > @LongitudeLow
    AND [Longitude] < @LongitudeHigh                
    AND [your exact radius calculation] <= 
      (CASE WHEN [DeliverlyLimit] < @Radius THEN 
          [DeliveryLimit] ELSE @Radius END)
```

Also for better performance, don't use SELECT * or sub-queries if you can avoid it. Return only IDs, and make a covering index for ID, Latitude, Longitude, and DeliveryLimit. Cache all the data from your table into an array of objects where the index is the ID so matching from the result set is quick.

Comment: PJ7 Thank you for your solution, I particularly like your advice regarding keeping the selection fields tight and the performance advice :)